# hql query gives an error

Tags: hadoop, hql, cloudera, tweets

I try to execute this query in hql

```
SELECT
  t.retweeted_screen_name,
  sum(retweets) AS total_retweets,
  count(*) AS tweet_count
FROM (SELECT
        retweeted_status.user.screen_name as retweeted_screen_name,
         retweeted_status.text,
         max(retweet_count) as retweets
      FROM tweets
      GROUP BY retweeted_status.user.screen_name,
               retweeted_status.text) t
GROUP BY t.retweeted_screen_name
ORDER BY total_retweets DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Anyone can help me to fix this?

Comment: Is this the only error ? Can you paste the entire error log

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:179)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
atorg.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Comment: ple tell me how do i add log file to this its too long

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing
 writable {"filter_level":"low","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
"id":841280691061084160,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"timestamp_ms":"1489411921645","in_reply_to_status_id":null,
"created_at":"Mon Mar 13 13:32:01 +0000 2017","favorite_count":0,"place":null,"coordinates":null,

Comment: "text":"RT @Ayourb: President Muhammadu Buhari resumes, receives briefing from the Vice President,
 Prof Yemi Osinbajo at the State Hous\u2026 ","contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"filter_level":"low","retweeted":false,
"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":true,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
"id":841279816603168768,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Mon Mar 13 13:28:33 +0000 2017",
"favorite_count":0,"display_text_range":[0,140],"place":null,"coordinates":null,

Comment: Please edit ur post and add these logs in your question

Comment: The comments where not clear , but it looks like the data parsing dint work fine. Please verify the delimiters used in the data file and the table is same

Answer (score 0):

I think you need write sum(t.retweets) AS total_retweets, instead of sum(retweets) AS total_retweets,